# Do magnetic monopoles exist?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

According to Gauss's law in magnetism, we know that there is no magnetic monopoles. But my teacher told in the class that magnetic monopoles exists but he didn't told us where instead told to search and find. Do magnetic monopoles exist anywhere on Earth?

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's related, but not a duplicate.  That one is about theoretical reasons for believing that they might exist.  I tried to find a duplicate of this, but I couldn't find one.   I'd be surprised, though, if it were not a duplicate.  I've never been good at searching this site for duplicates.

Comment: This question is already answered: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261246/

Answer (score 8):

No free magnetic monopoles have ever been confirmed to exist.

There have been experimental results that are consistent with the existence of monopoles, most famously on Valentine's Day, February 14 in 1982, but that observation has never been repeated and is now dismissed as an artifact of some kind.  No experiment has confirmed the existence of magnetic monopoles.

Monopole-like behavior has been observed in complex solids known as spin ices. However, these are not the free monopoles that one usually means when one speaks of magnetic monopoles.  Rather, the monopole-like behavior comes from specific arrangement of spins in these solids.  They are not separate particles.   They are what's sometimes called "quasi particles".